# Detecting contours of predefined shape with OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I'm working on a project which locates the Machine Readable Zone on ID cards.
For this I need to do some pre processing to extract the ID card from a scanned image which typically are randomly disposed on a white page. I'm able to locate the majority of the cards by using a Histogram equalization with CLAHE before a contour detection. But in some cases the border around the MRZ is totally invisible (white on white) as shown on the attached image.

I'd like to detect rectangle of a predefined shape as I know the shape of the ID card will be always the same but so far I wasn't able to find a way do do something like this with OpenCV.

[image: Example Scan]

Basically what I need is to find two rectangle of a fixed ratio that best match the 2 cards on the scan.

I'm wondering if I need to try OpenCV matchers or if there is a simpler way to accomplish this kind of detection.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to you problem is likely going to be matrix transformations. The concept is to pinpoint 4 coordinates on the card that can be easily detected using opencv, such as the the rectangle colored in blue & cyan.

Have coordinates of the card with the predefined shape stored in an array, where a corner of the card is at the `0, 0`. Also store the coordinates of the blue * cyan rectangle in an array. With the two arrays you can find the perspective transform of the two arrays using the `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform` method.

Using the perspective transform found, you can detect the coordinates of the whole card every time you detect the coordinates of the blue & cyan rectangle.